# Finding the closest solution to a system of linear equations

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-programming

I have a matrix A of size MxN where M>N and a vector b size M. I want to solve Ax=b as close as possible to b given I know that the system of equations is not solvable. In other words, I want to find x that will give me a vector that is closest to b. Looking online, it seems like I could reduce A down to its basis (linear independent vectors) and then find the projection of b onto that basis. However, I am not sure how to do this in python. I understand it would have something to do with qr decomposition, but I am not sure what the next step would be. And how it would be possible to recover x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a least squares solution via [`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

```
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)
```

Comment: Is this the same as taking the projection of vector B against the basis of matrix A? Will it give the same solution?

Comment: It should be similar to taking the [pseudo-inverse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) of the matrix which is based on singular-value decomposition (keeping the largest values only).